# Android selector states

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to change the background tint of a button when it is pressed (tapped once), but I can't find the right state for a selector. The closest I got is `state_pressed`, but it only works when you hold the button (not one tap).
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/greyColor" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

`state_checked` is what you're looking for.

If your button doesn't support `state_checked`, let it implement `Checkable` interface. Another way to achieve it is to use other state - `state_activated` or `state_selected`.

Answer (score 0):

You add state_selected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
</selector>
```

And change status selected when clicked:

```
btnTint.setOnClickListener {
        btnTint.isSelected = !btnTint.isSelected
}
```